# Why does the Google Maps DirectionsService return different routes?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have strange problem with the Google Maps DirectionsService. It returns me different routes if input data is the same. Here is a sample of my code

```
var path = [];
path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(51.10600101811778, 17.025117874145508));
path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(51.1047951799623,17.02278971672058));
path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(51.10456276619924, 17.02208161354065));
path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(51.10131895649719, 17.029248476028442));
path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(51.100331957810134, 17.033969163894653));
path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(51.10001867395775, 17.032413482666016));

for (var i = 0; i <path.length-1; i++) {
    var request = {
        origin: path[i],
        destination: path[i+1],
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
    }

    directionsService.route(request, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            selected_path = selected_path.concat(results.routes[0].overview_path);
            poly.setPath(selected_path);
            poly.setMap(map);
        }
    })
}
```

First time after the call, a function draws a strange polyline that always connects the start point with end point:

[image]

The second time it is called, the function works well and the route is drawn properly:

[image]

It's only example of input static data. Normally I work with dynamic data on matrix and dynamic markers, but always the same goes on. Firstly, start point is connected with end point + strange connection between other points. Second call function works well. Does somebody of you have some clue how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's only a guess: I believe what's happening is the path is getting concatenated out of order, because the directions requests are asynchronous. (Data does not necessarily come back in order). What I did below is place each leg of the directions in order in an array, then flattening the array into a continuous list, and display only after the right number of requests came back successfully.

I couldn't reproduce your zigzag so I don't exactly know if this answer will really solve the problem.

```
// count number of directions requests that returned successfully
var count = 0;

for (var i = 0; i <path.length-1; i++) {
  var request = {
    origin: path[i],
    destination: path[i+1],
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
  };

  // introduce variable scope to preserve value of i
  (function(i) {
     directionsService.route(request, function(results, status) {
       if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
         selected_path[i] = results.routes[0].overview_path;
         count++;

         // draw path only if all segments are completed
         if(count == path.length-1) {
           //flatten selected_path into 1-d array
           selected_path = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], selected_path);
           poly.setPath(selected_path);
           poly.setMap(map);
         }
       }
     });
   })(i);
 }
```

Comment: I've noticed that sometimes when I set my markers google.maps.DirectionsStatus isn't OK and polyline isn't drawn, maybe it's connected with walking mode. I will check it with driving mode.

Comment: @Martus0 Yeah, I lazily didn't add any error-checking or fall back when parts are missing. It is really complicated what you can do, because you can't tell if the Google service is just slow or there's no possible route. My best suggestion is to add a timeout with new Date()? Or in an else statement (if status is not OK) try connecting the previous and next dots (if they exist)? I think it's tricky.

Comment: I like else statement, it should really be helpful in such a situation :)

Comment: I was also thinking of adding a gap, in this case the first thing that comes to mind is splitting the single path to two different variables. But it sounds complicated. You can instead use a separate variable saying [true, true, false, true] for service status (false=not OK) and from there you can connect the endpoints :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You can call the function by a timer and set it to 250 millisecond to give you the best result. When you call service by "for" loop this problem will happen.

Here is the method:

```
//Counter for timer.
var counter2 = 0;

//Set a timer to pass latitude and longitude values to "draw_line()" function.
var timer = setInterval(function(){draw_way(new google.maps.LatLng(arrayLatitude[counter2], arrayLongitude[counter2]));

counter2 = counter2 + 1;

//Check if calue of timer is > "arrayLatitude.length" because if it becomes bigger it can't draw the way.


if(counter2 >= arrayLatitude.length)
{
    clearInterval(timer);


}
}, 250);
```

Comment: This is the Google service (route):                             draw_way(new google.maps.LatLng(arrayLatitude[counter2], arrayLongitude[counter2])